# gdb not catching std::out_of_range thrown by vector

Tags: c++, gdb, mingw

Compiling the following with MinGW 4.6.2 (with g++ -g -std=c++0x), gdb doesn't seem to want catch the `std::out_of_range` if I try `catch throw`. if I `throw` it manually it catches fine, am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> vec(10);
    try {       
        vec.at(10); // this won't be caught by gdb

        // throw std::out_of_range(""); // this will
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range const& e) {        
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've seeen, the exception from `std::vector::at()` is thrown by `__throw_out_of_range` which is a function inside `libstdc++.so`, so I suspect there's some problem on Mingw that prevents GDB from setting a catchpoint in a shared library. Or maybe your `libstdc++` wasn't built with `-g`.

If your GCC was configured with `--enable-libstdcxx-debug` you would have a second set of libs built with `-O0 -g` that might work better when debugging, but that option isn't used often.

Answer (score 4):

Add a breakpoint where `std::vector` throws the exception. At this moment, no stack unwinding has occured yet so you should be able to fully backtrace to the original statement.

I was able to achieve this, but only in a very implementation-defined way:

**1)  Locate the vector's range checking function in `stl_vector.h`:**

```
_M_range_check(size_type __n) const
{
    if (__n >= this->size())
          __throw_out_of_range(__N("vector::_M_range_check"));
}
```

**2) Add a breakpoint to the line where __throw_out_of_range() is called.**
Note: I tried adding a breakpoint by 'break __throw_out_of_range' but this did not work. Instead, I need to hardcode the breakpoint with it's file and line number (`break stl_vector.h:794`).
You can add this to your `.gdbinit` file to have gdb break on all failed range checks.

Comment: Good catch.  Now adding a break point in QtCreator seems to work.

Comment: Thanks. I found in modern gdbs (8.3) `break __throw_out_of_range` works without file::line; used for std::unordered_map. The standard `catch throw std::out_of_range` still does not.

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually catching exception in gdb. Try `catch catch` to [catch exception](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html).

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with msys2/mingw64 and setting this breakpoint made gdb stop where the throw occurred:

```
(gdb) b std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt
```

it also works with other exceptions, e.g. to catch std::bad_function_call exception, use this:

```
(gdb) b std::__throw_bad_function_call
```